# Trying to get my login page to respond properly to invalid/valid inputs

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently trying to get my login page (using spring boot/Thymeleaf) to respond to invalid inputs (wrong email/password) by showing the same page but with an additional message saying "Email or Password is incorrect". Its not working thus far, and it seems like my controller isn't even interacting with the inputs at all. The reason I think this is because when I submit invalid inputs it doesn't return to /login like it is specified in the controller's Post method, instead it goes to "http://localhost:3307/login?error", which makes me think that the controller's post method isn't working at all. Here is my html code (using some bootstrap template) and my UserController.

HTML code (its maybe a little messy)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                            <form id="login-form" class="form" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
                            <p th:if="${invalidCredentials}" class="error">Email or Password is incorrect</p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="text-info">Email:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
                            </div>
                            <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
                                <a href="#" class="text-info">Register here</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    UserRepository userRepo;
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        User user=new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        //Checking if User exists and if information is correct
        if(userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent()) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(user.getEmail());

            //Wrong PassWord
            if(!userDetails.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
                model.addAttribute("invaldCredentials", true);
                return "login";
            } 
            //Correct info given, redirecting to home page
            else {
                return "home";
            }
        } 
        //No existing User affiliated with given Email
        model.addAttribute("invalidCredentials", true);
            
        return "login";
    }
}
```

My WebSecurityConfigurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserService userService, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**", "/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();;
        
        return http.build();
    }

    
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAutenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ayoub Elmo, is that a form login that you're using? How did you setup your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: @dsp_user, Yes I am using formLogin. I also added permition to the login page. I added my WebSecurityConfigurations above.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a login error, you can tell Spring to redirect to another page that'll handle the error (this is done when configuring the Spring web security)

```
....
.authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/loginFailure")
```

If you don't specify a page for failed logins, Spring will simply return your login page with an error parameter (e.g /login?error ), You can access this parameter in Thymeleaf and display the error to the user then.

```
   <div th:if="${param.error != null}" >
                    
        <span  >Wrong credentials </span> 
                    
    </div>
```

Also, there's no need to write your endpoint (loginUser in this case) to handle the login process as Spring will do this automatically for you provided that you've set up the AuthenticationManager properly.

Comment: I do something similar in the html file, using                                                                         <p th:if="${invalidCredentials}" class="error">Email or Password is incorrect</p>                    Which should occur if the information given doesn't match any existing user profile. The check is performed by the Post method in my UserController (can see it above). The issue I am having is that this is not working. The check doesn't occur and the error message I have set up doesn't show if given incorrect input.

Comment: @Ayoub Elmo, like I said in my post, Spring will handle the login process automatically so you shouldn't try to verify the password manually in your code. Just make sure that the AuthenticationManager is configured properly. This call UserService.loadUserByUsername is basically handled completely by Spring. So remove your userLogin method altogether, you don't need it.